# Access object from json output

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

Hello guys I am new to nodejs and I am trying to access object in json and getting output from moongoose.

This is the code I use:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('hidden');


var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    link: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // object of all the users
  console.log(users);
});
```

This is the output:

```
[ { __v: 0,
    link: 'google.com',
    name: 'google',
    _id: 5665589cb813b33c385edec2 },
  { link: 'yahoo.com',
    name: 'yahoo',
    _id: 56655f3facc5c2203ccb5c71 } ]
```

How can I put "google.com" & "yahoo.com" in simple individual variables?

Thanks in advance.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var google = users[0].link;
var yahoo = users[1].link;
```

Or if you want to loop through users:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var link = users[i].link;
    console.log(link);
}
```

These are just some basic operations on JavaScript arrays. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks i had a confusion with square brackets.

i was following codes in github.. json.stringify, json.parse
Got confused... Thanks for the help mate....